# There is two Java class "Currency.java" and "Main.java",i want when i'll Run the main class method, HKD and MYR should not be same same

Tags: java

Here is the code for both classes "Currency.java" and "Main.java".

/*.......Currency.java ..........*/

package money;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Currency implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8228779577409316939L;

```
private final java.util.Currency javaCurrency;

private final String numericCode;
private final String currencySymbolOverride; // use to override the currency code in java.util.Currency
private final String description;
private final int hashCode;

private final int scale; // the number of sub-units of the currency (e.g. US dollars have 100 sub-units, or pennies)

// supported currency codes
private static final String CURRENCY_CODE_USD = "USD";
private static final String CURRENCY_CODE_HKD = "HKD";
private static final String CURRENCY_CODE_MYR = "MYR";
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL_USD = "$";
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL_HKD = "HK$";
private static final String CURRENCY_SYMBOL_RM = "RM";

// supported currencies
public final static Currency US_DOLLAR = new Currency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_USD), "840", 100, "US dollar");
public final static Currency HK_DOLLAR = new Currency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_HKD), "344", 100, "Hong Kong dollar");
public final static Currency MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT = new Currency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_MYR), "344", 100, "Malaysian ringgit", CURRENCY_SYMBOL_RM);


public Currency() {
    javaCurrency = null;
    numericCode = null;
    currencySymbolOverride = null;
    description = null;
    hashCode = 0;
    scale = 0;
}


public static Currency getByCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode)
{
    if (CURRENCY_CODE_USD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode))
    {       System.out.println("this is USD"+pCurrencyCode);
        return US_DOLLAR;
    }

    if (CURRENCY_CODE_HKD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode))
    {   System.out.println("this is HKD"+pCurrencyCode);
        return HK_DOLLAR;
    }

    if (CURRENCY_CODE_MYR.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyCode))
    {       System.out.println("this is MYR"+pCurrencyCode);
        return MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT;
    }

    return null;
}

public static Currency getByCurrencyAbbreviationOrSymbol(String pCurrencyAbbreviationOrSymbol)
{
    if (CURRENCY_SYMBOL_USD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyAbbreviationOrSymbol))
    {
        return US_DOLLAR;
    }

    if (CURRENCY_SYMBOL_HKD.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyAbbreviationOrSymbol))
    {
        return HK_DOLLAR;
    }

    if (CURRENCY_SYMBOL_RM.equalsIgnoreCase(pCurrencyAbbreviationOrSymbol))
    {
        return MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT;
    }

    return null;
}


public static boolean isSupportedCurrencyCode(String pCurrencyCode)
{
    return getByCurrencyCode(pCurrencyCode) != null;
}


private Currency(java.util.Currency pCurrency, String pNumericCode, int pScale, String pDescription)
{
    this(pCurrency, pNumericCode, pScale, pDescription, null);
}


private Currency(java.util.Currency pCurrency, String pNumericCode, int pScale, String pDescription, String pCurrencySymbolOverride)
{
    javaCurrency = pCurrency;
    numericCode = pNumericCode;
    description = pDescription;
    hashCode = Integer.parseInt(numericCode);
    scale = pScale;
    currencySymbolOverride = pCurrencySymbolOverride;
}


public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (this == o)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
    {
        return false;
    }

    final Currency currency = (Currency) o;
    return numericCode.equals(currency.numericCode);
}

public int hashCode()
{
    return hashCode;
}


public String getCurrencyCode()
{
    return javaCurrency.getCurrencyCode();
}


public String getSymbol()
{
    return currencySymbolOverride == null ? javaCurrency.getSymbol() : currencySymbolOverride;
}

/**
 * @return has the default currency symbol been overridden
 */
public boolean hasSymbolOverride()
{
    return currencySymbolOverride != null;
}


public String getSymbol(Locale locale)
{
    return javaCurrency.getSymbol(locale);
}

public String getNumericCode()
{
    return numericCode;
}


public int getScale()
{
    return scale;
}


public String getDescription()
{
    return description;
}


public int getDefaultFractionDigits()
{
    return javaCurrency.getDefaultFractionDigits();
}


public String toString()
{
    return javaCurrency.toString();
}

public java.util.Currency getJavaCurrency()
{
    return javaCurrency;
}


public static Currency newInstance() {
    return new Currency();
}
```

}

/*------Main.java----*/

package money;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Main extends Currency {

```
@Test
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Currency currencyUSD = Currency.getByCurrencyCode("USD");
    Currency currencyHKD = Currency.getByCurrencyCode("HKD");
    Currency currencyMYR = Currency.getByCurrencyCode("MYR");

    boolean currenciesAreSame = currencyUSD.equals(currencyHKD);
    if (currenciesAreSame) {
        System.out.println("USD and HKD currencies are the same.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("USD and HKD currencies are different.");
    }

    currenciesAreSame = currencyUSD.equals(currencyMYR);
    if (currenciesAreSame) {
        System.out.println("USD and MYR currencies are the same.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("USD and MYR currencies are different.");
    }

    currenciesAreSame = currencyHKD.equals(currencyMYR);
    if (currenciesAreSame) {
        System.out.println("HKD and MYR currencies are the same.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("HKD and MYR currencies are different.");
    }
}
```

}
  Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the help guide on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Copy pasting a bunch of code and saying "solve my problem" will not get you any help on this site.

Comment: i want to override the equals methods in main.java so that "currencyHKD.equals(currencyMYR)" will give the result "HKD and MYR currencies are different".

Answer (score 0):

You have the same numeric code (344) for HKD and MYR.

```
public final static Currency US_DOLLAR = new Currency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_USD), "840", 100, "US dollar");
public final static Currency HK_DOLLAR = new Currency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_HKD), "344", 100, "Hong Kong dollar");
public final static Currency MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT = new Currency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(CURRENCY_CODE_MYR), "344", 100, "Malaysian ringgit", CURRENCY_SYMBOL_RM);
```

Your `equals` method for Currency do the comparation using the numeric code. You need to define different numeric codes for HKD and MYR or modify your `equals` method for the Currency class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but code should be remain same as it is, Please assist further solution.

Comment: Is the initialization of `HK_DOLLAR` and `MALAYSIAN_RINGGIT` correct? They have the same numeric code (second parameter). If you can't modify the initialization of these object or the equals method of your `javaCurrency` class, then you always will get `true` when comparing these objects using equals.

Comment: The currency `equals` method check that the numeric code of the objects are the same. `HK_DOLLAR` object and `MALASIAN_RINGGIT` has the same numeric code and your equals method return true. What is your problem then?